# DotNet6 - projects not creating EXE

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

Had this problem after a VS2022 install, so I've been troubleshooting. Currently, I have NO Visual Studio installed.

Windows 10

```
Installed .net 6 sdk 
dotnet new console 
dotnet build 

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  net6console -> D:\net6console\bin\Debug\net6.0\net6console.dll
```

**NEVER** creates the EXE file. .
Any idea what is causing this ?

Comment: Yes, it has a program.cs 
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Here is the prj
```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>```

Comment: Delete the obj and bin directories and build again with `dotnet build -v diagnostic > c:\temp\log.txt`.  Open log.txt and search for AppHostSourcePath, copy/paste the output around the CreateAppHost task into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely removed ALL .net SDKs, reboot, install the Net 6.0.3 SDK and it creates and builds fine, and generates the exe

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the bin folder you will see that the exe file is created.

Comment: It does not . It creates the dll

Comment: What files do you see in `\bin\Debug\net6.0`?

Comment: I had all the dll/pdb files as I normally would. It just didn't create the .exe. It is a console project.  something was wrong with the .Net 6 sdk install apparently, see my answer below